# Origins of two creative steps used in discussion of the relevance of complex numbers. From Spivak's Calculus 2nd edition.

Tags: proof-explanation, cubics

The following is a passage from *Spivak's Calculus - Ch.25 - pg 519 - 2nd ed*. It revolves around the importance of complex numbers and solving for solutions:

[image]

[image]

My question revolves around where did the idea come from and what did the author ask themselves to use the substitutions:

$$x = y - \frac{b}{3} \\ x = w - \frac{p}{3w}$$

?

I see how they work, but as used plenty when teaching math, the substitutions seem to have been "pulled out of thin air". I'm trying to rectify that. So where did the notion come from to these things?

Comment: In my **uneducated** opinion, these approaches were the result of centuries of blind trial and error that finally paid off.

Comment: those substitutions get rid of the quadratic term, as indicated

Comment: Something to be aware of is that at the time (1520s-1540s) that the problem of solving cubic equations was being investigated, negative numbers were not considered legitimate in European mathematics. Solution of quadratic equations was taught in cases with positive coefficients only, so there were separate methods for $ \ ax^2 = bx + c \ , \ ax^2 + bx = c \ , $ and so on.  The solution of cubics came in stages via dal Ferro, Fontana ("Tartaglia"), and Cardano, the earliest of these being equations such as $ \ ax^3 = cx + d \ $ and $ \ ax^3 + bx^2 = d \ \ . $  [continued]

Comment: [continuing] So the idea of "eliminating" the quadratic term was somewhat easier to see as a critical step forward.  (What always makes this remarkable to me is that these methods were developed _without_ symbolic algebra, which Viete would only introduce late in that century.  The full-blown expression we learn as "Cardano's method" is an artifact of the _1600's._)  [If you have much interest in the history, there are a few books out in the past 25 years or so, the most recent being Fabio Toscano's _The Secret Formula_ (2020).]

Comment: One other thing about the first substitution:  it's not as blind a "stab" as all that.  What does the substitution for completing-the-square look like?  The $ \ -\frac{b}{2a} \ $ term was known in distant antiquity (though of course not in a symbolic form).  This is just "completing-the-cube".  After Viete and Descartes, it became clear that these substitutions are locating a symmetry-axis of the function curves:  the absolute extremum for the quadratic, the inflection point for the cubic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, the crucial observation (made in the 15 or 16th century - there was some priority dispute between Cardano and someone else) was that if $x=u+v$ then $x^3=u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)$ which immediately suggested to look for $u,v$ st $u^3+v^3+q=0, 3uv=-p$ so $x^3+px+q=(u^3+v^3+q)+(3uv+p)(u+v)=0$ and then $u^3+v^3+q=0, 3uv+p=0$ lead to a  quadratic in $u^3$.

Notice that then $x=u+v=u-p/(3u)$ exactly as shown in Spivak!

Answer (score 1):

If, in $x^3+bx^2+cx+d$, you replace $x$ with $x+k$, then you get$$x^3+(b+3k)x^2+Mx+N\tag1$$for some numbers $M$ and $N$. So, in order that $(1)$ is of the form $x^3+\alpha x+\beta$, $k$ shall have to be such that $b+3k=0$. In other words, $k=-\frac b3$.

Comment: Would the reasoning be that something along the lines of the highest degree of the polynomial is what dominates so we want to preserve that value and if we "can" eliminate" some of the lower powers in some form it can assist in finding solutions?

Comment: Something like that. I would say that if we eliminate one of the terms with lower degree, then the equation will become simpler and therefore it is more likely the we will be able to solve it.

Comment: One other question toward this, why would you replace $x$ with $x+k$ in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps because it works for quadratics: if, in $x^2+bx+c$, you replace $x$ with $x-\frac b2$, then you get another quadratice withou a term with degree $1$.

Comment: reducing the number of non-zero coefficients (as much as possible of course) is always a good idea on general principles (simplification etc)